# .NET Decimal formats differently depending on source

Tags: c#, number-formatting, fixed-point

I have a case which I've never seen before.

In one case, where we assign a decimal value via code, e.g. the value `foo.DecimalField = 200M;`
When I `ToString()` this with no formatter or culture, I get the value `"200"`

In another case, when the same field is assigned from EntityFramework, the debugger still says that the exact value of the field is `200M`, but when `ToString()`'ing it, it yields `"200.00"`

I would get that if it was a floating point problem here, or if there were hidden decimals in the debugger.

But since I'm using a fixed point decimal type, how can this be?
There is no webserver or anything that can affect culture or such involved.

What am I missing?
Can the decimal type behave differently depending on how it was initialized (I assume there is some reader that inits the decimal when fetching it from EF internally)

Comment: Perhaps you could make an SSCCE

Comment: `decimal` is still a floating point type, it is just in decimal rather than binary.

Comment: Decimal numbers preserve their precision when you perform operations on them, so if you got the two numbers through calculations with different precisions, this is expected behavior.

Comment: Also, if you want a consistent conversion, why not provide the format you want to `ToString()`?

Comment: I will ofcourse provide a format, I was just confused why this happened at all, my impression was that the decimal type always used the same precision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `Double`, `Decimal` *preserves zeros*, e.g.

```
  Decimal d0 = 200M;
  Decimal d1 = 200.0M;
  Decimal d2 = 200.00M;

  // 200 
  String St0 = d0.ToString();
  // 200.0 (or 200,0 depending on CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
  String St1 = d1.ToString();
  // 200.00
  String St2 = d2.ToString();
```

So it seems that in the process of computations, database reading etc. one value appeared to be `200M` while the other `200.00M`.

Comment: This "article" provides a bit of insight as well: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx (In short the exponent is stored, therefor it "knows" the number of decimals)